# Hardware Issue: GPU Artefacts on screen

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure, gpu, vram

After last time I cleaned my GPU (R9 290) and putted a heatsink on it started experiencing artefacts. Here are test results:

UEFI BIOS - Works fine.

Linux - Crazy artefacts all over screen.

Windows - Works fine with generic driver (vram recognized as 2048 MB), but wont even load (screen stays black or errors with: driver thread hangs) with proper driver installed.

After visual inspection of card I noticed tiny scratch on one of 16 memory chips. Could this scratch have damaged this memory chip and is causing this artefacts. Will the replacement of this memory chip fix this GPU?

[image]

**Update**: turns out artefacts are caused by heatsink, not putting enough pressure on a GPU chip.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a photo of the artifacts you see? // You won’t replace a BGA chip.

Comment: There is not enough detail in the image to see anything at all on the chip you are pointing out, let alone whether there is a scratch deep enough to cause damage to the actual IC. If it is a tiny surface scratch then chances are it is not the problem. Most likely is that in removing and replacing the heatsink it had not made good enough contact with the main GPU chip or there was not sufficient thermal compound.

Comment: Thanks, @Mokubai bad contact of a heatsink with the GPU seems to be the case here.

Comment: @AlexanderNovikov Fair enough, did reseating the heatsink properly fix the issue? If so it might be worth posting an answer so that it might help future users with a similar problem. Your new image is much better and as the scratch is only on the edge of the package and is relatively small I doubt it has caused any actual damage, it is unlikely that the actual IC is that close to the edge or surface of the plastic it is embedded in.